# The type initializer for 'ImageMagick.Types' threw an exception

Tags: c#, magick.net

I have just installed a Magick.net from the nuget and codeplex. 
I just want to write a sample application for compressing an image file by reducing its quality and DPI.

As per the little documentation which is available at codeplex, I written the below snippet.

```
MagickNET.Initialize(@"<<myPath>>\Magick.NET-x86.xml");

 using (MagickImage mImage = new MagickImage(txtSourceImage.Text.Trim()))
                    {
                        mImage.Quality = 33;
                        mImage.Depth = 8;
                        mImage.Density = new MagickGeometry(850, 550);
                        mImage.Write(tempFilePath);
}
```

it gives me an error, "The type initializer for 'ImageMagick.Types' threw an exception"
Please any one help me. What is wrong here ?

Comment: `ctor` or `cctor` or `field initializer` of `ImageMagick.Types` is throwing the exception. Check inner exception for more info

Comment: You should not use 'MagickNET.Initialize'. It is used for the configuration files, not the xml documentation. Feel free to start a topic here also: https://magick.codeplex.com/discussions

Comment: BTW friends, 
I have found the resolution for my problem and I used System.Drawing assembly in .NET to achieving this resolution. 
SO no need to use Magick.net.

Answer (score 1):

to: 'user3598321':
About using the System.Drawing... - Have you seen the small note at the bottom of page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx ? You should move back to MagickNET again... ;-)

[image]